# gt Rows hide based on condition

Tags: r, gt

I have a gt table in R where I would like to hide rows based on condition. For example in mydata, I would like to hide all rows that satisfy the condition If col3 contains "X2" then hide those rows

```
mydata <- data.frame( Col1 = c("A", "A", "B","B", "C","C"), 
                  Col2 = c("A1", "A1", "B1", "B1", "C1","C1"), 
                  Col3 = c("X1", "X2", "X1", "X2","X1","X2" ), 
                  Col4 = c(40, 42, 45, 38, 39,"NA"), 
                  Col5= c(45, 54, "NA", 32, 25,47))
```

expected output table

There are example for columns but non for rows. Is there a way to achieve this in gt?

```
outputdata <- data.frame( Col1 = c("A", "B", "C"), 
        Col2 = c("A1", "B1", "C1"), 
        Col3 = c("X1",  "X1", "X1" ), 
        Col4 = c(40,  45,  39), 
        Col5= c(45, "NA", 25))
```

Comment: Why not simply filtering your data before passing it to `gt`, i.e. `mydata %>% filter(col3 != "X2") %>% gt()`? At least from the docs it looks as if there is no equivalent to `cols_hide`.

Comment: @ Stefan, I know that I can filter it out with 'gt(mydata |> filter(Col3=="X1") )' . I don't want to filter it. I simply want to hide the rows when displaying the table in gt() – 
Pio

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [which](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/which). Here is the exemple :

```
> mydata[which(mydata$Col3 != "X2"),]
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
1    A   A1   X1   40   45
3    B   B1   X1   45   NA
5    C   C1   X1   39   25
```

`which` is a function that will return a vector of `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on the given condition. Here the condition is `mydata$col3 != X2`. If a row has a `col3` value set to `X2`, the vector will have `FALSE` for the corresponding index, so it will be filtered out.

Comment: There is no need to use `which`: `mydata[mydata$Col3 != "X2",]` will do.

Comment: @Yama  but I don't want to filter the rows=X2, just to hide it from displaying  it in the table